# Global structure variable is giving error as undeclared in particular function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
};    
struct node* head;    
void insert(int );    
void print();    

int main()    
{    
int n,i;    
printf("Enter the no. terms to be inserted");    
scanf("%d",&n);        
for(i=0;i<n;i++)           
{    
    int x;    
    printf("Enter the %dth term to the linked list : ",i+1);    
    scanf("%d\n",&x);    
    insert(x);    
}    

print();    

}    
void insert(int x)    
{    
    struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));    
    temp->data=x;    
    temp->next=head;    
    head=temp;    
}    
void print()    
{    
   int i=1;    
   struct node* temp=head;    
   while(temp!=NULL)    
    {    
       printf("The %dth element is : %d\n",i,temp->data);    
       temp=temp->next;    
       i++;    
    }    
}
```

### why this program is giving these errors :

sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c

main.c: In function 'insert':

main.c:29:24: error: 'node' undeclared (first use in this function)

     struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        ^
main.c:29:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:29:29: error: expected expression before ')' token
     struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I downvoted your question because the answer is very obvious and can be found by simply reading the error message...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C program - Structure marked as undeclared in compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764969/c-program-structure-marked-as-undeclared-in-compiler)

Answer (score 3):

Because you wrote `node` instead of `struct node` in that line.

In C, the structure declared with `struct node {...}` is called `struct node`. It is *not* just called `node`.